# How to setup Rest proxy on kafka clusture (excluding confluent or any other third party licensed )?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

Every search returns the Confluent pages for Kafka REST proxy.

Is there any other way to setup with the vanilla application or any open source ones?

Comment: Voting to close as question is asking for external tools/resources. Please refer [help]

Answer (score 0):

I think the community licensed ones are free to you use. Please check the following page https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/image-reference.html

Also you can consider this : https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/#api_reference-bridge if you need only a bridge for integration.